# Reverse Engineering (Stack overflow attack) with strcpy

Tags: assembly, x86

the c code is under like this,

```
void foo (char *x){
    int buf[1];
    strcpy((char *) buf, x);
}

void callfoo() {
    foo("abcdefghi");
}
```

and part of assembly code foo is

```
leal 0xfffffffc(%ebp), %eax
pushl %eax
call 80483c4 <strcpy>
movl %ebp, %esp
popl %ebp
ret
```

I expected the strcpy gets %eax to be filled with with buf, so It fills up to %ebp-4, %ebp, %ebp+4(old %ebp) %ebp+8(return address of foo).....
my attack string is "abcdefghi"

buffer will be filled with under the case,

```
%ebp-0x4 = 64636261
%ebp = 68676665
%ebp+0x4 = 08040069
```

But solution says it will fill up %ebp ~ %ebp+0x8. I misunderstood of stack structure?

Solution says,

```
B. Immediately before the ret instruction at address of foo, what is the value of the frame pointer register %ebp?

%ebp = 0x68676665

C. Immediately after the ret instruction of foo, what is the value of the program counter register %eip?

%eip = %ebp+8(it is changed by strcpy)
```

Comment: Think of `%ebp` as a pointer. It points to an address, `buf`, to which it will try to write your 10 byte string literal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I misunderstood push instruction.

the push instruction is

```
pushl %ebp
```

is same as

```
subl 0x4, %esp
movl %ebp, (%esp)
```

so strcpy is filled up to %ebp ~ %ebp+0x8